# Grok NameError on tal:attributes="action view/url"

Tags: zope, grok

I'm following the [Grok tutorial](http://grok.zope.org/doc/current/tutorial.html#storing-data) and I'm getting an error on the

```
 tal:attributes="action view/url"
```

portion of a POST form.  I assume this plops in the URL, but I'm confused as to why I'm getting the following error.

```
  File "/root/.buildout/eggs/Chameleon-2.8.5-py2.6.egg/chameleon/utils.py", line 404, in __getitem__
    raise NameError(key)
NameError: url

 - Expression: "view/url"
 - Filename:   /root/Sample/src/sample/app_templates/edit.cpt
 - Location:   (3:29)
 - Source:     <form tal:attributes="action view/url" method="POST">
                                        ^^^^^^^^
```

I have no experience with Zope or Grok: what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue what is the actual reason for the problem (was also just following the tutorial), but it seems that if you replace the problematic place with `tal:attributes="action view.url()"`, the error disappears and you can continue with the tutorial.

(No one cared to answer this for two years, heh)

Comment: Can you try `tal:attributes="action python: view.url()`, `tal:attributes="action view.url()` should not really work?? btw. I did not follow the tutorial, but `view.url()`is python so `tal` should run it as python not as tal expression.

Comment: Works this way too. Unfortunately, the tutorial seems to be dead currently, and eventually impossible to complete (e.g. there's a chapter missing), so this whole issue is not too relevant now I believe.

Comment: As far as I see it, Grok looks abandoned, so not worth digging too deeply into. It is still a decent way to get a quick understanding of "Zope-style" object publishing concepts.